# Video in original VC continues playing after switching to a different tab in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, video, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I currently have a view controller that is playing a video. When i click a tab in in the tab bar, I switch to a new VC but the audio from the original video is still playing. Is there any way to stop the audio?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Call

```
playerLayer.pause()
```

in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear in the first viewController.

Answer (score 0):

try this, works for me:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let center = CGPoint(x: postsTableView.center.x + postsTableView.contentOffset.x,y: postsTableView.center.y + postsTableView.contentOffset.y)
    
    guard let centerIndex = self.postsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: center) else {return}
    print("center point - \(center)")
    print("centerIndex - \(centerIndex.row)")
    let autoPlayCell = postsTableView.cellForRow(at: centerIndex) as? allPostsCell
    autoPlayCell?.vedioView.player?.pause()
}
```